# ActiveMQ STOMP over Websockets Remote Host name

Tags: node.js, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm trying to connect to an ActiveMQ instance from node.js using [STOMP.js](https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs) which connects via STOMP over websockets. My broker has a security policy enforced by a `BrokerFilter`:

```
package com.mycompany.queues.security;

import com.mycompany.domain.businessObjects.User;
import com.mycompany.domain.services.UserService;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.Broker;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.ConnectionContext;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Subscription;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerInfo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class BrokerAuthentication extends BrokerFilter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BrokerAuthentication.class);
    private UserService userService;
    private List<String> noAuthIPs;
    private static final Pattern IP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*://([0-9A-Za-z\\.]*).*");
    private static final Pattern CUSTOMER_ID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*customer_id\\s*=\\s*(\\d+)\\s*.*");

    public BrokerAuthentication(Broker broker, UserService userService, List<String> noAuthIPs) {
        super(broker);
        this.userService = userService;
        this.noAuthIPs = noAuthIPs;
    }

    @Override
    public void addConnection(ConnectionContext context, ConnectionInfo info) throws Exception {

        if (requiresAuth(context)) {
           //...
        }

        super.addConnection(context, info);
    }
    //...

    private boolean requiresAuth(ConnectionContext context) {

        String remoteAddress = context.getConnection().getRemoteAddress();
        Matcher matcher = IP_PATTERN.matcher(remoteAddress);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String ip = matcher.group(1);

            if (noAuthIPs.contains(ip)) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            log.info("IP not in no auth list " + remoteAddress);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

where I've omitted some irrelevant stuff. `NoAuthIPs` is set in a config xml file, and should include localhost.

When I attempt to connect to the broker from the same machine, I'm getting this error logged by `requiresAuth`:

```
IP not in no auth list StompSocket_814158251
```

Going digging through the activemq source code it seems as if there's 29 different implementations of the `Connection` interface, but I'm having trouble finding one that could possibly give me `StompSocket_814158251` as the remote address.

I've tried grepping for `StompSocket` in the node library on GitHub, and drew a blank.

I can't just add that specific string to my "allowed hosts" because of the random numbers at the end, and it's obviously not secure to try and add some catch-all workaround like matching `StompSocket` against a regex just because I don't understand it.

**Where is this weird remote address coming from, and how can I configure my auth around this behaviour?**

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
My ActiveMQ version is 5.11.1

My connection configuration for the node Stomp.js client:

```
  const { AMQ_HOST, AMQ_PORT, AMQ_USERNAME, AMQ_PWD } = process.env;
  //...
  new Client({
    brokerURL: `ws://${AMQ_HOST}:${AMQ_PORT}/stomp`,
    connectHeaders: {
      login: AMQ_USERNAME,
      passcode: AMQ_PWD
    },
    debug: function (str) {
      logger.info(str);
    },
    reconnectDelay: 2,
    heartbeatIncoming: 4000,
    heartbeatOutgoing: 4000
  });
```

where in my `.env` file I have

```
AMQ_HOST = localhost
AMQ_PORT = 61614
```

Comment: To find the implementation object you could simply call `System.out.println(context.getConnection().getClass());` in your `requiresAuth` method. That would help you narrow down your investigation.

Comment: Also, the `StompSocket` is a broker-side class, not a client-side one. See `org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.jetty9.StompSocket`.

Comment: Thanks @JustinBertram I've updated my post.

Comment: Does anything change if you use the actual IP/hostname of the machine instead of `localhost`?